# When trying to print out elements in a list lesser than 10 within 1 line of code, why is the address outputted instead

Tags: python, list, formatting

I expected this print statement to print each element lesser than 5 one at a time but got the address returned instead.

Any idea what to do if I want to print each element lesser than 5 one at a time within 1 line of code

```py
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
print(num for num in a if num < 5)
[out]:
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7efd6ce74cf0>

# This is the correct solution if I want to print it in a list
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
print([i for i in a if i<5])
[out]:
[1,1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am new to python but as far as I know this is the best way to do what you are asking.

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
print("\n".join([str(num) for num in a if num < 5]))
```

this is just the same code as the one you use above but I have also added the .join() method to separate out each element of the list and print it on a separate line. I used the "\n" to print everything on separate lines though if this is not what you wanted you could simply change that to an empty string: "" or a space: " ".

not sure if this is exactly what you are asking but I hoped it helped.

Comment: This seems to be the most obvious way of achieving the dessired output. Just for your info, you can make this slightly more efficient by removing the square brackets (because the list comprehension is inside another function, i.e. `print("\n".join(str(num) for num in a if num < 5))`. This turns it from a list comprehension to a generator comprehension, the join can still join the elements of the generator together, but does not need to build the list in memory first. Trivial difference for such a short list but worth knowing, all the same.

Answer (score 0):

Doing the for loop inside [] brackets is a [List Comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=list%20comprehension#list-comprehensions)

You can instead re-factor your code to for loop through each item in the list then print if one is less than 5 doing the following:

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
for x in a: print(x) if x < 5 else 0
```

The output for the following code is:

```
1
1
2
3
```

The above code is the same as doing:

```
for x in a:
    if x < 5:
        print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
list(map(print, (num for num in a if num < 5)))
```

Comment: The output of the above lines is :

1
1
2
3
[None, None, None, None]

Why the **[None, None, None, None]** is extra?

Comment: If you print out the value of the list it gives you the [None, None, None, None] (which corresponds to the return value of `print(num)` that is executed during the creation of the list (print doesn't actually return a value contrary to what you might expect!). I assume you ran my code in the python console that's why it did that but if you put it in a script and ran it you won't get the [None, None, None, None] part.

Comment: Correct!, Thank you

Comment: btw if you want to completely mitigate that replace it with this `_ = list(map(print, (num for num in a if num < 5)))` (yes that is an underscore)